# ¿Por qué este código me lanza un error y como solucionarlo? Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Quiero hacer `Tk` que tenga un botón y que al pulsar en el ejecute una función que abra un `Toplevel` que tenga un Entry y un botón y que al pulsar retorne el valor introducido en el entry.
Código:

```
from tkinter import *
def hija():
 
    ## Crea la ventana hija.
    t1 = Toplevel(root,bg="blue")
 
    ## Establece el tamaño para la ventana.
    t1.geometry('400x200+20+20')
 
    ## Provoca que la ventana tome el focus
    t1.focus_set()
 
    ## Deshabilita todas las otras ventanas hasta que
    ## esta ventana sea destruida.
    t1.grab_set()
 
    ## Indica que la ventana es de tipo transient, lo que significa
    ## que la ventana aparece al frente del padre.
    t1.transient(master=root)
 
    ## Crea un widget Label en la ventana
    L=Label(t1, text='Introduce la contreseña',bg="blue").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
 
    ## Crea un widget que permite cerrar la ventana,
    ## para ello indica que el comando a ejecutar es el
    ## metodo destroy de la misma ventana.
    B=Button(t1,text="Cerrar",bg="green", command=t1.destroy).pack()
 
    ## Crea un entry.
    e=Entry(t1,bg="lightyellow")
 
    ## Establece el focus en el entry.
    e.focus()
    e.pack()
 
    ## Pausa el mainloop de la ventana de donde se hizo la invocación.
    t1.wait_window(t1)
    return e.get()
 
## Crea la ventana para la aplicación
root = Tk()
 
## Establece un título y un tamaño para la ventana
root.title('Ventana principal')
root.geometry('800x400+10+10')
 
## Crea una etiqueta.
Label(root, text='Esta es la ventana principal').pack(pady=10)
 
## Crea un botón, desde el cual se puede lanzar una
## ventana de tipo modal.
Button(root,text="ventana", command=lambda: print(hija())).pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python\tkinter\zavir\VentanaHija.py", line 52, in <lambda>
    Button(root,text="ventana", command=lambda: print(hija())).pack()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python\tkinter\zavir\VentanaHija.py", line 38, in hija
    return e.get()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3043, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!entry"
```

Comment: Qué error? En qué línea?

Comment: @FedericoMeza ya esta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Tu error se debe a que el método wait_window termina cuando se cierra la ventana. Cuando se cierra la ventana, tratas de obtener el valor de un entry que ya no existe, ya que fue eliminado.

#### Solución

Nota: todo lo que se hace en esta solución se hace dentro de la función `hija`.

Tendrás que crear una función que guarde en algún lado el contenido del entry antes de destruir la ventana. Para eso vamos a crear una variable que inicie en None:

```
entry_value = None
```

Y una función llamada cerrar que asignará a esta variable el valor del entry y cierre la ventana:

```
def cerrar():
    nonlocal entry_value
    entry_value = e.get()
    t1.destroy()
```

La asociamos al botón:

```
B=Button(t1,text="Cerrar",bg="green", command=cerrar).pack()
```

Y a la cruz para cerrar la ventana en la esquina superior derecha:

```
t1.protocol("DELETE_WINDOW", cerrar)
```

#### Produce luego ingresar 111 y presionar cerrar o la cruz

```
111
```

Comment: Por cierto, me alegro de que te desbloquearan de hacer preguntas :D

Comment: Yo también me alegro de que contestes a mis preguntas con tanta calidad ^_^